# Install javaFX on docker image

Tags: java, linux, docker, javafx

I have a image based on Linux (CentOS Linux) with Java OpenJDK 11. I'm trying to install javafx on the image by this dockerfile:

```
USER root
yum -y update   && \
yum install –y openjfx
```

But when i try to build the image I get "No package javafx available." and " yum install OCoy javafx' returned a non-zero code: 1" What am I doing wrong? Is there another way of including JavaFX libraries on a docker image?

Comment: Do you want to create a custom openjdk-based jdk or jre that includes JavaFX modules? (Answer would be jdk or jre or something else with a better explanation).

Comment: I want to include the JavaFX modules. I found this https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven . And I'm trying now to specify the modules in the pom file and copying them to the image. Not sure if it will work

Comment: It’s not clear to me what you are trying to do, but if all you need is a custom Java runtime for your chosen platform that includes JavaFX modules, it is very to create one using [jlink](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jlink.htm#JSWOR-GUID-CECAC52B-CFEE-46CB-8166-F17A8E9280E9), which is part of any modern jdk distribution.

Comment: Or you could use [jpackage](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/specs/man/jpackage.html) to create an rpm, which your docker could install (from a yum repo if you wanted to put it there).  But then, as I said, I don’t know what you want so maybe my comments don’t apply to you or are just confusing.  Please ignore them if they are not relevant solutions to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could install an alternative JDK, for example [Liberica](https://bell-sw.com/pages/liberica_install_guide-11.0.11/#yum-repository-rpm-based-linux-distributions) or Corretto, which contain an OpenJFX-Distribution.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but using an alternative JDK is not an option for me. I should have mentioned it in the question.

Comment: Then probably, you might need to download the OpenJFX package manually (via cURL for example) and extract its lib-content into $JAVA_HOME/lib and bin-content to $JAVA_HOME/bin of course. That should do the trick eventually. However, that's kinda error prune, since you would need to have that download link up to date inside of your Dockerfile or shell scripts. Another approach might be to download it to your host and let docker build copy it to the correct destinations.

Comment: Yes that might be a little error prune. Could I get/download the javafx jar files from maven repo and copy them to the right location in the Dockerfile?

Comment: What you'd want to do is described [here](https://developer.tizen.org/development/articles/openjdk-and-openjfx-installation-guide). You basically want to download a distribution vom gluonhq.com depending on your operating system and you are good to go. You could also get the OpenJFX-JARs from Maven, but you'd have to look at the platform, too. No way around that of course. (However Docker is always linux arm or amd64). 
Benefit of gluonhq distribution is for example added source code.

Comment: “using an alternative JDK is not an option for me” -> why?

Comment: Sometimes when addressing comments, I find it useful to edit the question, quote the text of the comment in the question and write the response there rather than in the comment field.  Then you get unlimited-length responses and retain full editing and formatting options, which you don't get in comments, as well as usually improving the answer quality.  Just a suggestion.

Comment: @edean When getting the OpemJFX JARs from maven, what do youy mean by "but you'd have to look at the platform"?

Comment: Have a look at https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openjfx/javafx-graphics/15.0.1/ .
That's the repository entry for 15.0.1-javafx-graphics. The JARs exists with several classifiers. Aside from sources and javadoc, you also have JARs for win, mac and linux. As said, for Linux, you always need the ones with the linux classifier.